# What is the best way to bind buttons and handle its states (something like RadioGroup)?

Tags: android

Remember when we used tabs, then pressing on one tab would turn that tab ON and all other tabs OFF.

Now, imagine 4 buttons in the middle of an `Activity` which represent tabs. Clicking on each buttons will turn that button to ON state, and all others to OFF state, and will accordingly load a fragment below these 4 buttons.

Right now, I have coded these buttons' states via `foreach` loop where I set the button states.

Is there a better way to do it? Something like `RadioGroup` and `RadioButton` where setting states is done automatically.

Comment: So, basically, it's a RadioGroup with **custom RadioButtons** (i.e.: without the "circle").

Comment: [ToggleButttons](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html)? [This may also help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22186523/how-do-i-make-my-toggle-button-act-like-a-radio-button/22186545#22186545)

Comment: Yes, you can remove the button. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163628/adding-custom-radio-buttons-in-android - The accepted answer seems just perfect.

Comment: Guys, you are right. Silly question and silly me.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [android swipe view tab layout example](http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/12/android-swipe-view-tab-layout-example.html)! This code cycles among fragments (activities) based on which tab is pressed. Is this what you're looking for?

Please note that `tabhost`, another way of setting up tabs, is depricated.